# android SearchableDictionary sample - suggesting words

Tags: android

i just used the `searchabledictionary` sample of android, which is available in `samples` folder of android sdk for windows. ( API level 9 )

i completed the `definitions.txt` file with the same format like
`key - value`
when i type a word in search area, the app tries to suggest words, but it doesn't find the exact word.here is an example. i searched the word `test` , and this is `definitions.txt` :

> acceptance test - meaning
>
> acid test - meaning
>
> alpha test - meaning
>
> benchmark tests - meaning
>
> ....
>
> flight test - meaning
>
> load test - meaning
>
> ....
>
> test - meaning

it finds 15 first words of this list, ( hopefully it doesn't search words like `attestaion`)  but it doesn't show the exact word `test` !

i read the `DictionaryProvider` and `DictionaryDatabase` but i could not realize the root of problem!

the question is how can i suggest the exact word `test` at first of the list?

Answer (score 0):

Check Dictionary.java, you will see loadWords function.
That function opens definitions.txt file and iterates all lines, and splits every line with "-" and adds to a Hashmap dictionary.

And again in same file there is getMatches function, which takes your search keyword and gets result from dictionary.

Not sure but because when you are searching a suggestion, first couple of matches displays.
And  because of "test" keyword exists on too many lines and ("test - meaning") is your last  definition, you can't see on suggesting list.

You could try to move "test -meaning" line to the very first line on definitions.txt.

Comment: it is not a good idea to move "test -meaning" to first line of text file, because this is just a example, i want to set the user defined word at first of list, not the word `test` for always!